# Test Database Class in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

I have a class which does basic db operations such as save, retrieve and delete object in the DB. It has an `establishConnection()` method which is called before each operation.

I also have another class which calls the `saveObject` method from the DB class to store a graph it creates if it does not exist just before returning it in the getter. To test this getter I tried junit but it fails at the part where it stores the object and gives me `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` when i first set the graph and then just try to retrieve it but when i call the getter without setting the graph first so that the graph will be created then i get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`. I need to test both the classes with unit testing but I am not able to find any simple to follow example.

DB class outline:

```
public final class DbUtils {

    private static Connection connectionDB;

    private static void establishConnection() { 
     ...
    }

    private static void closeConnection() {
     ... 
    }

    public static void saveObject(final Object graph, final Object map) {

        establishConnection();

        //convert Objects to Byte and store it;

        closeConnection();
    }

    public static Map<String, Object> retrieveObject(final String key) {
        establishConnection();
        //read byte and convert to object
        closeConnection();
        return multireturn;
    }

    public static boolean deleteObject(final String key) {
        establishConnection();
        //delete all object except object with key
        closeConnection();
        return (affectedRow >= 1);

    }

}
```

GraphCreation class:

```
public class GraphCreation {
    Graph graph;
    ...
    private createGraph(){....}

    public void setGraph(Graph G){
        this.graph=G;
    }

    public Graph getGraph(){
        if(this.graph==null){
            createGraph();
        }
        saveToDB(graph, map);
        return this.graph
    }

}
```

Current Test:

```
@Mock
GraphCreation graph;

@Test
public void testSettingDependencyGraph() {
    graphCreation.setGraph(graph);
    Assert.assertEquals(Graph, graphCreation.getGraph());
}

@Test
public void testCreatingGraph(){
    graphCreation.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    graphCreation.setGraph(new Graph());
    moduleRegistrationBeans = new HashMap<String, ModuleRegistration>();
    ModuleRegistration m1 = new ModuleRegistration();
    m1.setName("module1");
    SDF1 = new TestSourceDataFactoryTemplate();
    VM1 = new TestModuleTemplate();
    m1.setSourceDataFactory(SDF1);
    m1.setModule(VM1);
    moduleRegistrationBeans.put("module_1", m1);
    PowerMock.reset(BeanFactoryUtils.class);
    PowerMock.mockStatic(BeanFactoryUtils.class);
    EasyMock.expect(BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(applicationContext, ModuleRegistration.class)).andReturn(moduleRegistrationBeans);
    PowerMock.replay(BeanFactoryUtils.class);
    graphCreation.getDependencyGraph();
}
```

Both the tests fails at the saveToDB() method in the GraphCreation class.
I am new to unit-testing and these test were written by some other dev, i added a DB feature and now the unit test fails. 
Can someone help me or guide me towards how can i fix this and create unit test for the DB class.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are over-burdening yourself; or the other way round: you try to do many things ... without having much of an idea what you are doing.

First: `DbUtils` has **static** methods. That is a "straight forward" task, but there are some subtle things to get right. If you mess up there, it simply doesn't work. Thus: you have to exactly follow all the steps outlined [here](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockitousage#mocking-static-method).

But more importantly: you do not understand what **mocking** is essentially about. Meaning - this here:

```
@Mock
GraphCreation graph;
```

together with

```
graphCreation.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
graphCreation.setGraph(new Graph());
...
```

simply doesn't make **any** sense.

When you tell Mockito (or PowerMock, or any other framework) to **mock** a class, then you create a **mock**. That mock only "appears" to be of that class under test; but it is nothing but an "empty shell". That object is in **no way** related to your production code. In other words: calling methods on that mock object like you do is a **no op**. That doesn't achieve *anything* useful!

Instead: you instantiate an object of the *class under test* using `new`! Maybe you **provide** mocked objects to that "real" object; because that real object needs those mocked things within the unit test environment. Then you call a method on the real object; and you "assert" on the result on that; or you maybe verify that the mocks provided to the real object saw the method calls you expected to see.

Long story short: step back, and read how to do unit tests properly, and how mocking comes into play there. Start reading [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html).

Beyond that: using **static** methods all over the place is *bad practice*. You should seriously consider to replace that solution with a non-static version (or at least: put a wrapper around the static class). Because then you would also be able to do your testing **without** PowerMock.

Finally: that NoClassDefFoundError indicates that you are trying to run something ... but one/more required class is missing from your classpath setup. Probably because you got your mocking wrong.

But the point is: slow down; and **understand** what you want to do. Instead of building a huge, complex problem that actually consists of many subtle not-knowings about the things you are doing.